# Plotly in Jupyter issue

Tags: python, plot, jupyter, plotly, jupyter-notebook

I installed plotly.py to work some plots using Jupyter but I cannot import it.

```
! pip install plotly --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: plotly in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: requests in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from plotly)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from plotly)
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from plotly)
Cleaning up...
```

and then

```
  import plotly
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c27a4132ad2e> in <module>()
----> 1 import plotly

  ImportError: No module named 'plotly'
```

I'm running Python 3.4.1, so as Jupyter, and the thing that I cannot get is that plotly works just fine when I'm running Python from the command line. Any suggestions? (I really don't want to clean install Python)

Answer (score 21):

Running following on command prompt solved my issue.

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly
```

It is likely that the plotly installed via pip install is somehow not detected by Jupter.

Comment: It didn't worked. 
In terminal if I call 
    python3; 
    import plotly

, it's ok but not in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 3):

In the jupyter notebook, running the correct kernel you want the package to be installed, run

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} plotly
```

This installs plotly within the correct kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by going through the directories. pip install is installing in default python lib folder, a more in-depth answer is here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48774224/9176740

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24118287)

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb thank you for ur feedback, i have updated it accordingly. Ill be more careful with my future answers :) have a nice day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Using plotly.plotly creates errors with different versions of python.

1. ensure you don't have multiple version of python installed and in your environment variables path.
2. Try from now to work with 'chart-studio'.

Run

```
 'pip install chart-studio'
```

and then import using:

```
 'import chart_studio.plotly as py'
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip install plotly.
this problem usually occurs on cloud anaconda navigator when you need to plot a Plotly graph in a python program
here is the solution.I suggest
simply run these commands on window prompt or on git bash

Answer (score 0):

To import seaborn, sklearn and plotly on jupyter notebook first run this on terminal for python "pip install ipykernel", for anaconda "conda install ipykernel" or "python -m ipykernel install"

Answer (score 0):

probably it is a venv issue.
Try starting jupyternotebook as follows and install plotly from whithin which will ensure that you are running jupyter from your environment.

```
python -m jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the cufflinks library along with the plotly.

```
pip install plotly
pip install cufflinks
```

This solved the plotly no module error on the Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

! pip install plotly --upgrade fix the error in my error but pip install plotly from cmd in anaconda did not help

Comment: Welcome to SO!It is very useful if you add the error message (with proper formatting) to your question. I would suggest you edit your question with the exact error you are getting so people can help you better and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly
```

this code solved the problem.  I executed this code in anaconda prompt.

Answer (score -1):

After a while searching about this problem, I discovered it is a broken conda-kernel trough jupyter notebook.

Inside your notebook **check if it is pointing to the write python executable's envinronment path** by:

```
import sys
sys.executable 

# >>>> 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\**wrong_env**\\python.exe'
```

**If it isn't**, the simple solution is to `install nb_conda`:

```
conda install nb_conda
```

Comment: That package is for an extension that provides a GUI for managing Conda envs in Jupyter. This likely ended up installing `jupyter` in your Conda env, which, while perhaps sufficient, is unnecessary and an improper way to solve a misconfigured Jupyter setup.

Comment: How so improper if it fixes misconfigured settings? I've stated that it solved to me as an aditional way of solving if others find the other answers insuficient. All you've said is your opinion.

Comment: But it doesn't "fix misconfigured settings", i.e., the disconnect between your existing Jupyter installation and the env you want to use - it instead creates an entirely new installation of Jupyter. Proposing `nb_conda` is also misleading as to the underlying problems (not having configured your env to work in Jupyter - [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)) and suggests that installing an unnecessary component somehow fixes things.

Comment: Again, **it fixed for me** and it might fix for someone else which problem is not as complex as OP's, wether you think is a solution or not. I'm just leaving it here in case someone is trying to fix and nothing works. The above might.

Comment: also: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/245#issuecomment-348546719