# Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I installed Anaconda (with Python 2.7), and installed Tensorflow in an environment called `tensorflow`. I can import Tensorflow successfully in that environment.

The problem is that Jupyter Notebook does not recognize the new environment I just created. No matter I start Jupyter Notebook from the GUI Navigator or from the command line **within** the `tensorflow` env, there is only one kernel in the menu called `Python [Root]`, and Tensorflow cannot be imported. Of course, I clicked on that option multiple times, saved file, re-opened, but these did not help.

Strangely, I can see the two environments when I open the `Conda` tab on the front page of Jupyter. But when I open the `Files` tab, and try to `new` a notebook, I still end up with only one kernel.

I looked at this question:
[Link Conda environment with Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433363/link-conda-environment-with-jupyter-notebook)
But there isn't such a directory as `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels` on my computer! This Jupyter directory only has one sub-directory called `runtime`.

I am really confused. Are Conda environments supposed to become kernels automatically? (I followed https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html to manually set up the kernels, but was told that `ipykernel` was not found.)

Comment: `conda install ipykernel` seems to install `jupyter` in the environment... Am I missing something?

Comment: presumably ipykernel has jupyter as a dependency?

Comment: no longer seems to work...see answer below from Andreas

Comment: @ThomasK this works only if `nb_conda` is used or if the kernel is setup manually as suggested in the question. Otherwise it will actually mess up things quite a lot. The executable `jupyter` will point to an executable inside the environment, but system's `jupyter-notebook` will be started (if installed) and therefore not use the environment with the default kernel.

Comment: I've written a comprehensive debugging guide in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment/58068850#58068850

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook

Answer (score 878):

I don't think the other answers are working any more, as conda stopped automatically setting environments up as jupyter kernels. You need to manually add kernels for each environment in the following way:

```
source activate myenv
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

As documented here:http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments
Also see [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/245).

Addendum:
You should be able to install the `nb_conda_kernels` package with `conda install nb_conda_kernels` to add all environments automatically, see https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels

Comment: Is is possible to somehow flag is at the most up to date solution as of today?

Comment: Installing `nb_conda_kernels` worked for me as of April 2018 (`Python 3.6.4`, `conda 4.3.27`, `jupyter 4.4.0`).

Comment: Could one have different `Jupyter` configuration file per `conda` environment? Namely `jupyter_notebook_config.py` per environment.

Comment: If this isn't working for you try running `conda install ipykernel` this answer assumes that you already have that installed on your environment.

Comment: This isn't working for me. If I load `jupyter notebook` in a certain environment, I still want to have my Jupyter notebook see all other conda environments that I have installed. So, inside Jupyter, `conda kernelspec list` does list my two environments. Their respective `kernel.json` points to two different python paths. However, if I do `jupyter notebook` inside a certain activated env, whatever kernel I am using, `!which python` always uses that python of the activated environment. Major limitation for me.

Comment: `nb_conda_kernels` not for python 3.9

Comment: If it's not working, after trying this, restart the VS Code once ! It helped me!

Comment: `conda activate myenv` worked for me instead of `source activate myenv`

Comment: it should be noted that this answer also works for people using `pip` instead of `conda` by simply running:

```pip install myenv```

```source myenv/bin/activate```

```python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"```

Answer (score 276):

If your environments are not showing up, make sure you have installed

- `nb_conda_kernels` in the environment with Jupyter
- `ipykernel` and `ipywidgets` in the Python environment you want to access (note that `ipywidgets` is to enable some Juptyer functionality, not environment visibility, see [related docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html#installing-in-jupyterlab-3-0)).

[Anaconda's documentation](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#installation) states that

> `nb_conda_kernels` should be installed in the environment from which
> you run Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab. This might be your base conda
> environment, but it need not be. For instance, if the environment
> notebook_env contains the notebook package, then you would run
>
> ```
> conda install -n notebook_env nb_conda_kernels
> ```
>
> Any other environments you wish to access in your notebooks must have
> an appropriate kernel package installed. For instance, to access a
> Python environment, it must have the ipykernel package; e.g.
>
> ```
> conda install -n python_env ipykernel
> ```
>
> To utilize an R environment, it must have the r-irkernel package; e.g.
>
> ```
> conda install -n r_env r-irkernel
> ```
>
> For other languages, [their corresponding kernels](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) must be installed.

In addition to Python, by installing the appropriatel `*kernel` package, Jupyter can access kernels from [a ton of other languages](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) including [R](https://irkernel.github.io/), [Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl), [Scala/Spark](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree), [JavaScript](https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript), bash, [Octave](https://github.com/calysto/octave_kernel), and even [MATLAB](https://github.com/calysto/matlab_kernel).

---

Note that at the time originally posting this, there was a possible cause from [`nb_conda` not yet supporting Python 3.6 environments](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/issues/45).

If other solutions fail to get Jupyter to recognize other conda environments, you can always install and run `jupyter` from within a specific environment.  You may not be able to see or switch to other environments from within Jupyter though.

```
$ conda create -n py36_test -y python=3.6 jupyter
$ source activate py36_test
(py36_test) $ which jupyter
/home/schowell/anaconda3/envs/py36_test/bin/jupyter
(py36_test) $ jupyter notebook
```

Notice that I am running Python 3.6.1 in this notebook:
[image]

Note that if you do this with many environments, the added storage space from installing Jupyter into every environment may be undesirable (depending on your system).

Comment: Hi Sorry to opening this thread again. However I tried everything as advised here and still dont see tensorflow env in jupyter. I have jupyter installed in the tensorflow env. I have python 3.6.1 installed there. I tried installing conda nb_conda but it says conflict with py3.6. So that didn't get installed rest everything else I have tried and doesn't seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: ok. I checked again. My issue is that my jupyter when opened up with Python 3 kernel is not able to import any modules. I am not sure why is that. And also it doesn't show other env too

Comment: @Baktaawar I noticed that same error. I wanted to flesh out this answer but ran into that and didn't have time to solve it. I think this is a bug that should be reported as a git issue.

Comment: Just found a git issue for the same. Apparently nb_conda doesn't work for py36 which means we cannot use py36 env in jupyter without nb_conda? Any hack anyone knows? 

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1423

Comment: You can use it (I do all the time). You just have to start Jupyter from the environment you want to use in the notebook.

Comment: i did that. It doesn't work because nb_conda doesn't work for python 3.6

Comment: I just got it. It won't work with python 3.6 since nb_conda is not working for python 3.6. But one can create conda env with 3.5 and it works then. Can change environment then in jupyter

Comment: @Baktaawar, see my updated answer demonstrating how to use python 3.6 in the notebook.  You can run a python 3.6 environment, you just have to start jupyter with that environment active.  Conda environments can be thought of as self contained python installations.  If you install Jupyter into your system python you would likewise only see one python kernel option.  `nb_conda`'s purpose is only to "[provide] Conda environment and package access extension from within Jupyter" not make it so you can run Jupyter from your chosen python installation.

Comment: On 10/4/2018 this worked for me.  I can now see my conda environments under the New dropdown selection list of jupyter web app.

Comment: @merv, thanks for the tip about `nb_conda_kernels`.  I just confirmed that works by installing miniconda, installing jupyter in the (base) environment, then creating a new environment.  I was indeed able to see the environment I created.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell thanks for addressing my concern. I think you still need to mention that `ipykernel` needs to be installed in each env you want to use as a kernel.

Comment: @merv In my testing, I actually do not have `ipykernel` in the environment I am accessing, only the environment where `jupyter` is actually installed.  It must have been installed as a dependency since I did not actively install it.  I am able to access the non-jupyter environment without it being installed.  As as [possibly irrelevant] side note, I checked on installing `ipykernel` in the "non-jupyter" env and noticed that it will also install `jupyter_client`, `jupyter_core`, `libsodium`, `pyzmq`, and `zeromq`.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell I'm just trying to advocate what is [clearly stated in the documentation](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#installation) and I know from experience works consistently and minimizes bloating envs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why it works without it.  You're right, they clearly state it should be installed.  I've added that to my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 125):

The annoying thing is that in your `tensorflow` environment, you can run `jupyter notebook` **without installing `jupyter` in that environment**. Just run

```
(tensorflow) $ conda install jupyter
```

and the `tensorflow` environment should now be visible in Jupyter Notebooks started in any of your `conda` environments as something like `Python [conda env:tensorflow]`.

Comment: I had the same problem as Thomas K, and the solution shared by Octavius solved my problem as well. However, there is one catch, if you have Python 3 version of Anaconda, then you would be able to see only your current active environment, and it should have it's own Jupyter. But if you install Python 2 version of Anaconda, it can handle all the environments.

Comment: you can do "conda install nb_conda" as well in Python2 version of anaconda to manage your envs from Jupyter itself.

Comment: @rkmalaiya is correct. If your running Miniconda3 or Anaconda3, perform ```conda install nb_conda``` in one of your sourced conda environments (which has jupyter notebook installed). You can then switch kernels/conda envs in the jupyter notebook browser.

Comment: That's interesting as installing tensorflow either with the tensorflow websites instructions or using conda install tensorflow have both messed up conda on two different machines in two different ways. The first time I've had any problems with jupyter and conda was right after installing tensorflow.

Comment: Can report this method works on Sep 2018 with Anaconda 5.2 Python 3.6

Comment: **This is a terrible answer** because it encourages users to install Jupyter in every env, which is completely unnecessary. The reason why this works is that `ipykernel` (which is the only thing actually needed), is a dependency of `jupyter`.

Comment: @merv: what's the best solution for this?

is `conda install nb_conda_kernels` the best solution, then?

Comment: @amandeep1991 I generally think that `nb_conda_kernels` is a clean, minimal solution. The only case I see use for installing Jupyter directly in an env is if one is actually developing a Jupyter extension and wants to include the version of Jupyter components as part of the project specs.

Answer (score 117):

I had to run all the commands mentioned in the top 3 answers to get this working:

```
conda install jupyter
conda install nb_conda
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name mykernel
```

Comment: This was what worked for me as well, but I didn't need `conda install nb_conda`

Comment: I just needed the first 3 commands to show the environment kernel as an option when I run `jupyter lab` inside that specific environment

Comment: Worked for me too. My god this was frustrating to figure out.

Comment: You don’t need nb_conda! ;)

Comment: I tried every answer an this is the only one that worked.  So, by the time I got to this answer, I had already executed the first three lines, that did not work, python -m ipykernel install --user --name mykernel is what did it.

Comment: I had some troubles with the compatibility of ipython. To fix it, I had to upgraded ipython using this command `pip install --upgrade ipython`.

Answer (score 64):

Just run `conda install ipykernel` in your new environment, only then you will get a kernel with this env. This works even if you have different versions installed in each envs and it doesn't install jupyter notebook again. You can start youe notebook from any env you will be able to see newly added kernels.

Comment: This is the best answer as of Jan 2018.  Jupyter should auto-discover your kernel on startup if you simply `conda install ipykernel` inside your conda environment.  Worst case, you can use `python -m ipykernel install --user --name mykernel` to manually generate the kernel, but you wouldn't want to do this if it's already auto-discovered, or it will show up twice in the kernel list.

Comment: this will also install Jupiter and all it's dependencies. It works but somehow it's not optimal

Answer (score 29):

#### Summary (tldr)

If you want the 'python3' kernel to always run the Python installation from the environment where it is launched, delete the User 'python3' kernel, which is taking precedence over whatever the current environment is with:

```
jupyter kernelspec remove python3
```

#### Full Solution

I am going to post an alternative and simpler solution for the following case:

- You have created a conda environment
- This environment has jupyter installed (which also installs ipykernel)
- When you run the command `jupyter notebook` and create a new notebook by clicking 'python3' in the 'New' dropdown menu, that notebook executes python from the base environment and not from the current environment.
- You would like it so that launching a new notebook with 'python3' within any environment executes the Python version from that environment and NOT the base

I am going to use the name 'test_env' for the environment for the rest of the solution. Also, note that 'python3' is the name of the kernel.

The currently top-voted answer does work, but there is an alternative. It says to do the following:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name test_env --display-name "Python (test_env)"
```

This will give you the option of using the test_env environment regardless of what environment you launch `jupyter notebook` from. But, launching a notebook with 'python3' will still use the Python installation from the base environment.

What likely is happening is that there is a user python3 kernel that exists. Run the command `jupyter kernelspec list` to list all of your environments. For instance, if you have a mac you will be returned the following (my user name is Ted).

```
python3       /Users/Ted/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
```

What Jupyter is doing here is searching through three different paths looking for kernels. It goes from **User**, to **Env**, to **System**. See [this document](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html#kernel-specs) for more details on the paths it searches for each operating system.

The two kernels above are both in the User path, meaning they will be available regardless of the environment that you launch a jupyter notebook from. This also means that if there is another 'python3' kernel at the environment level, then you will never be able to access it.

To me, it makes more sense that choosing the 'python3' kernel from the environment you launched the notebook from should execute Python from that environment.

You can check to see if you have another 'python3' environment by looking in the Env search path for your OS (see the link to the docs above). For me (on my mac), I issued the following command:

```
 ls /Users/Ted/anaconda3/envs/test_env/share/jupyter/kernels
```

And I indeed had a 'python3' kernel listed there.

Thanks to [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2898) (look at the first response), you can remove the User 'python3' environment with the following command:

```
jupyter kernelspec remove python3
```

Now when you run `jupyter kernelspec list`, assuming the test_env is still active, you will get the following:

```
python3       /Users/Ted/anaconda3/envs/test_env/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Notice that this path is located within the test_env directory. If you create a new environment, install jupyter, activate it, and list the kernels, you will get another 'python3' kernel located in its environment path.

The User 'python3' kernel was taking precedence over any of the Env 'python3' kernels. By removing it, the active environment 'python3' kernel was exposed and able to be chosen every time. This eliminates the need to manually create kernels. It also makes more sense in terms of software development where one would want to isolate themselves into a single environment. Running a kernel that is different from the host environment doesn't seem natural.

It also seems that this User 'python3' is not installed for everyone by default, so not everyone is confronted by this issue.

Comment: python -m ipykernel install --user --name test_env --display-name "Python (test_env)"  works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 26):

To add a conda environment to Jupyter:

In [Anaconda Prompt](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#write-a-python-program-using-anaconda-prompt-or-terminal) :

1. run `conda activate <env name>`
2. run `conda install -c anaconda ipykernel`
3. run `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=<env name>`

Answer (score 20):

```
    $ conda install nb_conda_kernels
```

(in the conda environment where you run jupyter notebook) will make all conda envs available automatically.  For access to other environments, the respective kernels must be installed. Here's the [ref](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels).

Comment: Doesn't this just recapitulate https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349338/570918?

Comment: This looks like the simplest way.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me in windows 10 and latest solution :

1) Go inside that conda environment ( activate your_env_name )

2) conda install -n your_env_name  ipykernel

3) python -m ipykernel install --user --name build_central --display-name "your_env_name"

(NOTE : Include the quotes around "your_env_name", in step 3)

Answer (score 14):

The `nb_conda_kernels` package is the best way to use `jupyter` with `conda`. With minimal dependencies and configuration, it allows you to use other conda environments from a jupyter notebook running in a different environment. Quoting its [documentation](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#installation):

> **Installation**
>
> This package is designed to be managed solely using conda. It should be installed in the environment from which you run Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab. This might be your `base` conda environment, but it need not be. For instance, if the environment  `notebook_env` contains the notebook package, then you would run
>
> `conda install -n notebook_env nb_conda_kernels`
>
> Any other environments you wish to access in your notebooks must have an appropriate kernel package installed. For instance, to access a Python environment, it must have the `ipykernel` package; e.g.
>
> `conda install -n python_env ipykernel`
>
> To utilize an R environment, it
>   must have the r-irkernel package; e.g.
>
> `conda install -n r_env r-irkernel`
>
> For other languages, their [corresponding kernels](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) must be installed.

Then all you need to do is start the jupyter notebook server:

```
conda activate notebook_env  # only needed if you are not using the base environment for the server
# conda install jupyter # in case you have not installed it already
jupyter
```

[image]

---

Despite the plethora of answers and @merv's efforts to improve them, it still hard to find a good one. I made this one CW, so please vote it to the top or improve it!

Comment: [Screenshot by Rich Signell](https://github.com/nds-org/esiphub/issues/2#issuecomment-381360320)

Answer (score 12):

This is an old thread, but running this in Anaconda prompt, in my environment of interest, worked for me:

```
ipython kernel install --name "myenvname" --user
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Previously, I was installing __ipykernel__ this way: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=<environment-name>`, but that method no longer seems to work, even though the environment appears as a kernel option.

Comment: This worked perfectly. After trying the method on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/1968932. Still environment was not visible. However, your trick seems to make it work in the end even when working inside a jupyter lab workspace after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 9):

We have struggle a lot with this issue, and here's what works for us.  If you use the [conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge), it's important to make sure you are using updated packages from `conda-forge`, even in your `Miniconda` root environment.

So install [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html), and then do:

```bash
conda config --add channels conda-forge --force
conda update --all  -y
conda install nb_conda_kernels -y
conda env create -f custom_env.yml -q --force
jupyter notebook
```

and your custom environment will show up in Jupyter as an available kernel, as long as `ipykernel` was listed for installation in your `custom_env.yml` file, like this example:

```
name: bqplot
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- python>=3.6
- bqplot
- ipykernel
```

Just to prove it working with a bunch of custom environments, here's a screen grab from Windows:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this same problem where my new conda environment, `myenv`, couldn't be selected as a kernel or a new notebook. And running `jupter notebook` from within the env gave the same result.

My solution, and what I learned about how Jupyter notebooks recognizes conda-envs and kernels:

Installing jupyter and ipython to `myenv` with conda:

```
conda install -n myenv ipython jupyter
```

After that, running `jupter notebook` outside any env listed `myenv` as a kernel along with my previous environments.

```
Python [conda env:old]
Python [conda env:myenv]
```

Running the notebook once I activated the environment:

```
source activate myenv
jupyter notebook
```

hides all my other environment-kernels and only shows my language kernels:

```
python 2
python 3
R
```

Answer (score 6):

This has been so frustrating, My problem was that within a newly constructed conda python36 environment, jupyter refused to load “seaborn” - even though seaborn was installed within that environment. It seemed to be able to import plenty of other files from the same environment — for example numpy and pandas but just not seaborn. I tried many of the fixes suggested here and on other threads without success. Until I realised that Jupyter was not running kernel python from within that environment but running the system python as kernel. Even though a decent looking kernel and kernel.json were already present in the environment. It was only after reading this part of the ipython documentation:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments
and using these commands:

```
source activate other-env
python -m ipykernel install --user --name other-env --display-name "Python (other-env)"
```

I was able to get everything going nicely. (I didn’t actually use the —user variable).

One thing I have not yet figured is how to set the default python to be the "Python (other-env)" one. At present an existing .ipynb file opened from the Home screen will use the system python. I have to use the Kernel menu “Change kernel” to select the environment python.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue and I found a solution that is working for Mac, Windows and Linux. It takes few key ingredients that are in the answer above:

To be able to see conda env in Jupyter notebook, you need:

- the following package in you base env:
  `conda install nb_conda`
- the following package in each env you create:
  `conda install ipykernel`
- check the configurationn of `jupyter_notebook_config.py`
   first check if you have a `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in one of the location given by  `jupyter --paths`
   if it doesn't exist, create it by running  `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
   add or be sure you have the following: `c.NotebookApp.kernel_spec_manager_class='nb_conda_kernels.manager.CondaKernelSpecManager'`

The env you can see in your terminal:
[image]

On Jupyter Lab you can see the same env as above both the Notebook and Console:
[image]

And you can choose your env when have a notebook open:
[image]

The safe way is to create a specific env from which you will run your [example of env](https://github.com/tarrade/proj_custom_ai_platform_notebook/blob/master/env/jupyter-notebook.yaml)`jupyter lab` command. Activate your env. Then add jupyter lab extension [example jupyter lab extension](https://github.com/tarrade/proj_custom_ai_platform_notebook/blob/master/script/jupyter_lab/install_jupyterlab_extension.sh). Then you can run  `jupyter lab`

Comment: Adding `c.NotebookApp.kernel_spec_manager_class=..` to Jupyter configuration fixed my issue GCP's AI Platform. My guess is the `nb_conda_kernels` package was installed, but it was not configured to work with Jupyter.

Answer (score 4):

While [@coolscitist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958537/1870254) worked for me, there is also a way that does not clutter your kernel environment with the complete jupyter package+deps.
It is described in the [ipython docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments) and is (I suspect) only necessary if you run the notebook server in a non-base environment.

```sh
conda activate name_of_your_kernel_env
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --prefix=/home/your_username/.conda/envs/name_of_your_jupyter_server_env --name 'name_of_your_kernel_env'
```

You can check if it works using

```sh
conda activate name_of_your_jupyter_server_env 
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Comment: actually, updating jupyter and using `conda install nb_conda_kernels` works better.

Comment: Just note that `python -m ipykernel install` is the traditional route of registering an env, and works for other (non-Conda) envs. The idea behind `nb_conda_kernels` is that you don't need to do manually do this, as long as you install `ipykernel`.

Comment: Yes! I turned this comment into [this standalone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409235/1870254).

Answer (score 4):

First you need to activate your environment .

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Next you can add your virtual environment to Jupyter by typing:

```
python -m ipykernel install --name = my_env
```

Comment: After installing ipykernal, this worked: python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"

Answer (score 4):

For conda 4.5.12, what works for me is (my virtual env is called nwt)

```
conda create --name nwt python=3
```

after that I need to activate the virtual environment and install the ipykernel

```
activate nwt
pip install ipykernel
```

then what works for me is:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name env_name --display-name "name of your choosing."
```

As an example, I am using 'nwt' as the display name for the virtual env. And after running the commands above. Run 'jupyter notebook" in Anaconda Prompt again. What I get is:
[image: new kernel]

Answer (score 3):

Follow the [instructions in the iPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) for adding different conda environments to the list of kernels to choose from in Jupyter Notebook. In summary, after installing `ipykernel`, you must activate each conda environment one by one in a terminal and run the command `python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"`, where `myenv` is the environment (kernel) you want to add.

Answer (score 2):

### Possible Channel-Specific Issue

I had this issue (again) and it turned out I installed from the **conda-forge** channel; removing it and reinstalling from **anaconda** channel instead fixed it for me.

**Update**: I again had the same problem with a new env, this time I did install `nb_conda_kernels` from **anaconda** channel, but my `jupyter_client` was from the **conda-forge** channel. Uninstalling `nb_conda_kernels` and reinstalling updated that to a higher-priority channel.

So make sure you've installed from the correct channels :)

Comment: Sounds like you may have the some things mixed up. `jupyter` and `nb_conda_kernels` should be installed in one env - this is where you always run `jupyter notebook` from. New envs only need `ipykernel`, but should not be activated when running `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: I'm aware, it was on a new machine.

Comment: Okay. I edited your answer, mostly so I could change my vote, but also to clarify what you were calling the **conda** channel (not a thing - either **defaults** or **anaconda**). Feel free to edit it further if I'm misstating what happened.

Comment: @merv: Is it possible to avoid installing a new `ipykernel` for each conda env?

Comment: @VimNing if you want to use it as a Python kernel in Jupyter, then no.

Comment: @merv Say I already installed `JupyterLab` into a standalone env, do I still need to install `nb_conda_kernels` for it nowadays?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when using vscode server.
In the conda environment named "base", I installed the 1.2.0 version of opennmt-py, but I want to run jupyter notebook in the conda environment "opennmt2", which contains code using opennmt-py 2.0.
I solved the problem by reinstalling jupyter in conda(opennmt2).

```
conda install jupyter
```

After reinstalling, executing jupyter notebook in the opennmt2 environment will execute the newly installed jupyter

```
where jupyter 
/root/miniconda3/envs/opennmt2/bin/jupyter
/root/miniconda3/bin/jupyter
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add to the previous answers: in case installing `nb_conda_kernels`, `ipywidgets` and `ipekernel` dosen't work, make sure your version of Jupyter is up to date. My envs suddenly stopped showing up after a period of everything working fine, and it resumed working after I simply updated jupyter through the anaconda navigator.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32479513)

Answer (score 0):

Using only environment variables:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name $(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated April 2023:** You have to activate conda environment and then install the below dependecies

```
conda activate timm_tutorial
conda install jupyter
conda install nb_conda
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name mykernel
```

After this, click on the `.ipynb` file, if it gives **Internal Error 500** then check to see your terminal log you got an error `AttributeError: module 'charset_normalizer' has no attribute 'md__mypyc'`

```
pip install chardet
```

I hope after that you can change the jupyter notebook kernel and run your script

Answer (score 0):

My solution, I working with WSL,
First: you need  `conda install nb_conda`
Second: `conda deactivate`
Third: `conda activate myenv`
Final: `jupyter notebook`
If you want check  `env` you choose, in homepage jupyter, choose tab conda, you can change another `env`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, using Windows 10 and conda 4.6.11, by running the commands

```
conda install nb_conda

conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels
```

from the terminal while having the environment active didn't do the job after I opened Jupyter from the same command line using `conda jupyter notebook`.

The solution was apparently to opened Jupyter from the Anaconda Navigator by going to my environment in Environments: Open Anaconda Navigator, select the environment in Environments, press on the "play" button on the chosen environment, and select 'open with Jupyter Notebook'.

Environments in Anaconda Navigator to run Jupyter from the selected environment

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#installation) on how to use Conda kernels.  You launch Jupyter from the env that has Jupyter; you install `ipykernel` in all envs that you wish to use in Jupyter as kernels.