# Jupyter conda tab 'An error occurred while retrieving package information.'

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, conda

In my root environment I run

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

and in the browser, click on the 'Conda' tab. This always used to list my conda environments and the packages in them. Now I'm greeted by the following error.

[image: Jupyter error box]

I recently created and deleted some conda environments, maybe that is relevant. The only console output is

```
[W 10:30:20.948 NotebookApp] 404 GET /environments?_=1476811818902 (::1) 13.19ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 10:30:20.951 NotebookApp] 404 GET /packages/available?_=1476811818903 (::1) 1.77ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

Comment: Having the same issue on a new install on a recently upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 installation I deleted the entire anaconda and reinstalled (created two env's and got the same result the envs are listed in the change kernel dropdown on a notebook but nothing on the conda page you have snapshotted. Very strange , another new machine of mine with Ubuntu 16.04 is working fine..

Comment: further info:
tom@tom-sam:~$ env | grep -e PATH
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
PATH=/home/tom/anaconda3/bin:/home/tom/gce/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/tom/Downloads/google_appengine/
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this issue:
https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/issues/23

The issue seems to be a conflict between the notebook config file in the `conda` environment and the config file in the users directory.

To fix the issue and get the tab to display properly the content, I had to remove that file:

`rm jupyter_notebook_config.json in ~/.jupyter`

Note that, for me, that was not an issue as it did not really contain anything.

Comment: Should have added I had to restart the Jupyter server in the conda env to get it to see the changes.

Comment: Delete file; restart server. Worked for me

Comment: This cannot really be a solution, what if you have actual parameters in the `jupyter_notebook_config.json`?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out at: https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/issues/23#issuecomment-239813091

The following command helped in resolving the issue:

```
jupyter serverextension disable nb_conda
jupyter serverextension enable nb_conda
```

This basically rewrites the config file in the ~/.jupyter folder.

Comment: Didn't help on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, running `conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels` worked for me.

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 0):

If no of the commands work for you, try adding kernels manually for each of the environments (as pointed out by [Andreas Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786736/8741356)):

```
source activate <my_environment>
python -m ipykernel install --user --name <my_environment> --display-name "<Display name>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `for env in info['envs']]` by `for env in info['envs'] if env != info['root_prefix']]` in this path`anaconda3\pkgs\nb_conda-2.2.1-py38_1\envmanager.py`
and that solve all errors

Answer (score 0):

For me I just needed to close the current Jupyter notebook session and start again, then the error disappeared and it was able to load the envs.