# How to solve "forbidden" error in jupyter notebook (conda tab)

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I installed anaconda and succeeded in making the conda-tab work thanks to the last suggestion in this entry: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41825208/6375668

However, when I try to create an environment or install an additional package I receive a "forbidden" error (see below). When I open anaconda-navigator I am perfectly able to create environments and install packages.

What could be wrong? And how to fix this? Thanks!

[image: "forbidden error"]