# Pytorch module error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, torch, pytorch

I installed pytorch using conda command when the virtual env was activated.

But, there are some problems when I import torch modules in Jupyter Notebook.

I checked the sys.path both in the prompt and in Jupyter Notebook.

Well.. in the prompt, the result of `sys.path` is

```
['', '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
     '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
     '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
     '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

and there are no errors when I import torch modules.

But, in the jupyter notebook(executed in chrome), the `sys.path` is

```
['',
 '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/usrname/.ipython']
```

and I see an error: `No module named 'torch'`

I can't solve this problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook?rq=1)

Comment: same problem: import succeeds from python but fails from ipython/jupyter

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issues with this but managed to solve the problem. I think PyTorch has an 'issue' with the regular Jupyter application in Anaconda, so I urge you to first install the numpy jupyter notebook that supports PyTorch, then you can launch you notebook again.
Use (while in your virtual env path):

`conda install numpy jupyter notebook`


Hope this helps.

Comment: For me the minimal command that worked on my virtual environment was `conda install jupyter notebook`. Thanks for the tip, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1.Create a conda virtual environment:

```
conda create -n env_pytorch python=3.6
```

2.Active this environment create above:

```
source activate env_pytorch
```

3.Install PyTorch with pip or pip3:

```
pip install torchvision --user
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to anaconda.navigator -> environments -> base(root) -> select not installed -> search 'torch' -> install
   2.run 'import torch' in your jupyter notebook!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a kernel in the virtual envs and choose that kernel in the jupyter.

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: If you want to have multiple IPython kernels for different virtual envs or condo environments, you will need to specify unique names for the kernelspecs. 
You can check the command in https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

Answer (score 0):

Use below command-

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```