# Jupyter Basemap and Cartopy Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I installed anaconda3-5.0.1 by pyenv. And I executed `conda create -n obspy python=3.6.4 anaconda` to make environment "obspy" use obspy.

I tried to use obspy along with http://docs.obspy.org/packages/obspy.clients.fdsn.html#module-obspy.clients.fdsn in Jupyter. And I executed `cat.plot()` the error `Neither basemap nor cartopy could be imported.` has occurred.

Basemap and Cartopy are already installed, and when the same commands are executed in command line they work well. I thought packages that were installed by `conda` command were not reflected the environment of Jupyter.

How can I reflect the environment of "obspy" to that of jupyter?

Comment: is the problem here that you `obspy` environment isn't showing up in Jupyter, for example when you click "new", you don't see `obspy` as a option?

Comment: Yes. I can only select Python3 when I click "New" in a top page of Jupyter.

Comment: Check this answer then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349338/2005869

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have Jupyter (and basemap) installed in the `obspy` environment and make sure you start Jupyter Notebook from that same environment.

Usually these kind of problems arise from not all packages being present in the very same environment.