# Cannot run fastai library on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, fast-ai

I hope this question is not redundant, but I couldn’t find a solution on the internet so far. I’ve followed the github guide (https://github.com/fastai/fastai) to install the fastai library on my Anaconda environment. I want to use this library to tackle the ML course and solve other Kaggle competitions with it.

As per below, I’m opening my conda environment, selecting fastai and opening Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

When trying to run the packages in Jupyter, I still get an Import Error with No module named ‘fastai’. Any suggestions on what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue. It looks like the problem is with "softlinks" fastai which are not working on Windows.
I fixed it with replacing that soflinks with real module fastai from root of repository. Just copied it to courses\dl1, courses\dl2, courses\dm1 and tutorials folders.

Prerry dirty. But works. Let me know how to fix it without copying.

Answer (score 1):

Add a cell to the beginning of the notebook, `!python -m pip install git+https://github.com/fastai/fastai.git`

Edit:

Now that fastai is 1.0 and on pip, you probably just want to `!python -m pip install fastai`.

I prefer the `!python -m pip` syntax over just calling pip when mixing anaconda and pip, but it probably just reflects my system's python being messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble making fastai_v1 work in jupyter lab, however it was working on the terminal. So the problem was with the virtual environment not being selected in the jupyter lab when it was launched.

I used the below code to make it work. Replace 'myenv' with your virtual environment name.

```
source activate myevn

python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"

jupyter lab
```

more info here: [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)