# Can't install installed python packages

Tags: python, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook to install packages with the command: !pip install. 
I just used this command to install the Options package, but it's still not showing up. I checked the default python Environment as well as the conda environment. 
[list of Python environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAfUY.png)

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy It is `!pip` inside a jupyter notebook

Comment: @Lauren Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 1):

To install packages into jupyter notebook you have to use `conda` instead of `pip`. Just find the conda install instruction for the package you are trying to install. 
For example, the command to install numpy on conda is:

```
conda install -c anaconda numpy
```

instead of the regular pip version which would've been:

```
pip install numpy
```

You can search for yours by googling:  `conda install <package-name-you-want-to-install>`.