# Python anytree application challenges with my jupyter notebook ​

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, anytree

I am working in python 3.7.0 through a 5.6.0 jupyter notebook inside Anaconda Navigator 1.9.2 running in a windows 7 environment. It seems like I am assuming a lot of overhead, and from the jupyter notebook, python doesn’t see the anytree application module that I’ve installed. (Anytree is working fine with python from my command prompt.)

I would appreciate either 1) IDE recommendations or 2) advise as to how to make my Anaconda installation better integrated.
​

Comment: I am working with the kernel solutions suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem with my python IDE environment was that I could not utilize the functions in the anytree module. The anytree functions worked fine from the command prompt python, but I only saw error messages from any of the Anaconda IDE portals.

Solution: 
1) From the windows start menu, I opened Anaconda Navigator, "run as administrator."
2) Select Environments. My application only has the single environment, “base”,
3.) Open selection “terminal”, and you then have a command terminal window in that environment.
4.) Execute [ conda install -c techtron anytree ] and the anytree module functions are now available.
5.) Execute [ conda update –n base –all ] and all the modules are updated to be current.