# Command line python and jupyter notebooks use two different versions of torch

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pytorch, conda

On my conda environment importing torch from command line Python and from a jupyter notebook yields two different results.

Command line Python:

```
$ source activate GNN
(GNN) $ python
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.__file__)
/home/riccardo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py
>>> print(torch.__version__)
0.4.1
```

Jupyter:

```
(GNN) $ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8890

import torch

print(torch.__file__)
/home/riccardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py

print(torch.__version__)
1.2.0+cu92
```

I tried the steps suggested in [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
$ conda install ipykernel
$ source activate GNN
(GNN) $ python -m ipykernel install --user --name GNN --display-name "Python (GNN)"
Installed kernelspec GNN in /home/riccardo/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/gnn
```

but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Please add for python and jupyter the output of the following commands to your question: `print(torch.__file__)` and `print(sys.path)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort of make the Anaconda environment recognized in Jupyter using

```
conda activate myenv
conda install -n myenv ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

Replace `myenv` with the name of your environment. Later on, in your Jupyter Notebook, in the Select Kernel option, you will see this `Python (myenv)` option.

Comment: If this answer helped, then you can click the green tick beside the answer to mark this question answered. Also upvote :D.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did upvote, but you can't see it as I have less than 15 reputation (just created account). Cheers

Comment: akshayk07 I've installed pytorch locally using conda, but want to be able to use it on Jupyterhub. Should your solution work for this? I don't want to try it in case it crashes something.