# How to get pytorch to work in Jupyterhub?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm using Jupyterhub, and am running someone else's code that uses `pytorch`. They include it via `import torch`, but I get the error "No module named 'torch'". I installed `pytorch` locally with `conda`, but still get the same error in Jupyterhub.

**What I Want To Know:**

For modules like pytorch that aren't part of Jupyterhub out of the box, how do you include them? Do you do it by installing them locally like I did? If so, what should I do differently?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58305717/7615877) might help you.

Comment: That answer applies to Jupyter notebooks, do you know if it should also apply to Jupyterhub?

Comment: Hey @gkeenley. Yes, the same steps should apply to your use case as well. Please try them once and let us know what other issues you face.

Answer (score 1):

Create a conda environment for installing pytorch.

```
conda create -n pytorch_env python=3 ( you can create with any python version )
```

Activate the environment.

```
conda activate pytorch_env
```

Now install PyTorch using:

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision -c pytorch
```

To get the installed pytorch in the jupyter notebook, follow the below instructions.

Install the ipykernel :

```
conda install ipykernel
```

Follow the command.

```
ipython kernel install --name pytorch_env --user
```

Now open the jupyter and select the "pytorch_env" from Kernel option. ( path : jupyter -> kernel -> change kernel -> pytorch_env )

Then import pytorch in jupyter notebook using:

```
import torch
```