# Error message launching jupyter in conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I created a new conda env: conda create -n test_env

python 3.8 was installed (remark: my python is 3.7.3 under windows10 and anaconda)

When launching jupyter notebook in this environment I got the following error (translated in english):

The entry point of procedure 
?PyWinObject_FromULARGE_INTEGR@@YAPEAU_object@@AEBT_ULARGE_INTEGER@@@Z 
can't be found in the dynamic link libary
<~user>AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\Library\bin\pythoncom37.dll.

I create again (after removal): conda create -n test_env python=3.7

and got same issue

When using already existing conda envs no issue, just on the new ones.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: There is good advice on using Jupyter with Conda in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409235/570918). In summary, you only install `jupyter` in one env, where you also install `nb_conda_kernels`. In all other envs you install `ipykernel`. Always launch `jupyter notebook` from the single env that has `jupyter` installed, then you can choose your the other envs as kernels.

Comment: Thank you for yoyr answer. When I create a new environment,, I activate it and then do the following: conda install ipykernel. But now I have this error message and don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I [followed this link](http://p1htmlkernalweb.mybluemix.net/articles/%E7%94%B1%E6%8D%A2jupyter+notebook%E7%9A%84%E4%B8%BB%E9%A2%98%E5%BC%95%E5%8F%91%E7%9A%84%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8debug%E7%9A%84%E8%BF%9E%E7%BB%AD%E5%89%A7%EF%BC%88%E4%BA%8C%EF%BC%89_3780174_csdn.html), though it couldn't solve my problem.

1. it's not only while starting jupyter
2. It also happened when I started spyder (from anaconda prompt) in the new env
3. When importing tensorflow in the new env.

This solved for me => deleted pythoncomXX.dll in the exact folder (<~user>AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\Library\bin\pythoncom37.dll.) and I never encountered the same problem => in the all the three cases mentioned above.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.:( And the link that you shared isn't opening up either. Can you please recheck the link?