# Anaconda Environment Error - procedure entry point could not be located for pythoncom38.dll

Tags: anaconda, python-3.8, pythoncom

I created a new environment in Anaconda 2.0.3 using Python 3.8.8 using `conda create -y --name gpu_env python=3.8`. In the next step, I install nb_conda using `conda install nb_conda`.

I repeatedly get the following error message at the execution stage

"The procedure entry point ?init@PyWinBufferView@@QEAA_NPEAU_object@@_N1@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\user123\anaconda3\envs\gpu2\Library\bin\pythoncom38.dll"

This happens during the 'enabling notebook extension nb_conda/main' , 'Enabling tree extension nb_conda/tree', and 'Enabling: nb_conda' as shown below

```
Executing transaction: \ Enabling nb_conda_kernels...
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\Users\user123\anaconda3\envs\gpu_env
Status: enabled

\ Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `EnableNBExtensionApp`.
Enabling notebook extension nb_conda/main...
      - Validating: ok
Enabling tree extension nb_conda/tree...
      - Validating: ok
Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `EnableServerExtensionApp`.
Enabling: nb_conda
- Writing config: C:\Users\user123\anaconda3\envs\gpu_env\etc\jupyter
    - Validating...
      nb_conda 2.2.1 ok

done
```

The pythoncom38.dll is present in location specified in the error message. I tried the following without success:-
(a)  Delete the pythoncom38.dll from the environment folder, and thereafter reinstall nb_conda
(b)  Uninstall Anaconda, and reinstall without including the PATH variable
(c)  Other ideas given in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980718/error-message-launching-jupyter-in-conda-environment) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409235/570918)

I could not find a working solution.

Can anyone throw some way ahead?

Comment: I am having the same problem; does someone is able to get to a solution? I already tried to replace the python38.dll but with no avail

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I suspect the file pythoncom38.dll on my environment was corrupted. So I replaced the file from my local environment and replaced it by the file pythoncom38.dll from the following website: https://www.pconlife.com/viewfileinfo/pythoncom38-dll/ and

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I open Notebook on virtual machine.
(Saw exactly same notification)
I use anaconda, but one of my colleagues installed Python and then installed Anaconda too, before he passed the virtual machine to me.
I removed both Python and Anaconda, and installed Anaconda only.
And issue fixed.