# windows anaconda environment not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda, conda

i'm created a conda environment

```
conda create -n tfgpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tfgpu
```

but now after running

```
(tfgpu) > jupyter notebook
```

I can't **import tensoflow as tf**, notebook doesn't load this environment!
Why it's happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved after:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786736/12370909

```
conda create -n tfgpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tfgpu
python -m ipykernel install --user --name tfgpu --display-name "Python (tfgpu)"
jupyter notebook
```

Then you could be able to create a new Notebook using your environment by selecting "Python (tfgpu)" from the drop-down list.

Comment: is it's okay that setting stored in "user" data directory, so they LEAK OUT of tfgpu environment?

Comment: Or, may be, I have two choices:
1) install jupyter into tfgpu environment (that spends additional space)
2) use anaconda's default jupyter notebook and accept the fact that
"system-wide package stores it's setting system wide"