# Use conda environment in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I am running Anaconda on windows 10 and using Jupyter Notebook for my Machine Learning projects.

I recently became aware of virtual environments in conda.

I created a virtual environment in conda using following command

```
conda create -n test1
```

activated the environment

```
activate test1
```

installed environment in ipykernel (not sure correct terminology is used)

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name test1
```

now the environment `test1` is visible in jupyter notebook but when i start it I am getting `kernel starting... please wait` message.

here are some snippets.

[image: Environment is showing while creating new file.]

[image: Kernel is busy always.]

also in jupyter prompt (again not sure about the terms) i am getting following error

```
[I 21:08:24.924 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in /MachineLearning/ImageProcessing
[I 21:08:29.550 NotebookApp] Kernel started: ec56795d-df5b-48d5-8f95-473ab1253407
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-125>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 527, in initialize
    self.init_sockets()
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 287, in init_sockets
    self.init_iopub(context)
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 295, in init_iopub
    self.iopub_thread = IOPubThread(self.iopub_socket, pipe=True)
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 68, in __init__
    self._setup_pipe_in()
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 141, in _setup_pipe_in
    self._pipe_in = ZMQStream(pipe_in, self.io_loop)
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._init_io_state()
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 546, in _init_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_handler(self.socket, self._handle_events, self.io_loop.READ)
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Users\shesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
[W 21:09:29.591 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from ec56795d-df5b-48d5-8f95-473ab1253407
[I 21:10:29.197 NotebookApp] Saving file at /MachineLearning/ImageProcessing/Untitled.ipynb
```

All I want to do is use newly created environment in jupyter notebook.

Comment: This really is a duplicate of "[Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)" Unfortunately, there are many misinformed answers on that thread, but I can recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409235/570918) specifically as a proper route.

Comment: @merv I followed the steps mentioned in the answer provided in your comments. I am confused though. Do I need to activate a particular environment everytime I want to do some development in jupyter using that environment?

Comment: Also I want to know what this ```NotImplementedError``` means. Is there any wrong step which I am performing? Why it is not working?

Comment: no you always activate and launch Jupyter from the env with Jupyter then you can choose the env you want to use as a kernel in the notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following steps:

```
source activate test1
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name test1 --user
```

Comment: i tried this solution but it didn't work. Actually after doing this only I am stuck in the current situation. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please check whether python path is correctly set in the control panel environment variables?