# another python version runs on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I created a conda environment with python3.6 and when I simply run `python` on terminal, pythonn3.6 comes up but when I hit a `jupyter notebook` command in the exact same environment, python3.7 starts runnning.
using Mac os, visual studio code. thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here -> [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)  always works for me

```
conda install jupyter
conda install nb_conda
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name mykernel
```