# How do i get jupyter notebook to recognize tensorflow?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-3.6

Hello I'm a highschool student and I was given the task of making a CNN. I am not very familiar with this type of coding. Every time we run the code in Jupyter Notebook this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-7d4e1bb634e9> in <module>
      8 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      9 import numpy as np
---> 10 import tensorflow as tf
     11 
     12 # Allow image embeding in notebook

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I've put it under Python 3.6 like my prof suggested and I am using tensorflow 1.4, which is the version I must use. I'm also working on mac os. He also said we can't put tensorflow under a virtual environment or else the program won't work. If there is any way to fix this problem through the terminal or otherwise it would be highly appreciated. Thanks for the help.
Edit: I am using jupyter notebook under anaconda. And Conda commands are not recognized for me.

Comment: if you have a virtual environment that has tensorflow is installed, you need to select the appropriate python kernel

Comment: If you're using conda environments, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/39604271/2662958

Answer (score 0):

## install Jupyter in user's local python library path

```
pip install --user jupyter
```

## install python virtual environment to be used as a Jupyter kernel

```
virtualenv -p python3 tf-venv
```

## activate the python virtual environment tf-venv

Note: this example was specific for tensorflow, but install as many as desired.

```
source tf-venv/bin/activate
```

## install tf-venv specific python packages

```
pip install tensorflow
```

## install ipykernel modlue

```
pip install ipykernel
```

## install tf-venv as a Jupyer kernel

Note: this will install the tf-venv kernel into your user's python local libraries in ~/.local

```
  pip install -m ipykernel --user --name=tf-venv
```

## deactivate your tf-venv virtual environment

```
deactivate
```

## start jupyter notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

[image]

Comment: I’m sorry. I forgot to specify that I am using jupyter notebook under anaconda

Comment: @aricado_13. I did this all on a MacBook Pro. Just open a terminal and issue the commands in the instructions above.

Comment: Thanks for your help! For some reason my terminal doesn't recognize the "-m" as an option. Is there maybe something else I could replace it with?

Comment: Using your terminal when you execute which python3

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did work for me except that last install command should be replaced with

```
python install -m ipykernel --user --name=tf-venv
```