# Changing jupyter kernels still falsely imports non-existing package

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I created a new conda environment `myenv` and the only package I installed is the uncommon package `astropy`.
I ran `jupyter notebook` out of this activated environment `myenv`, just to see that `myenv` isn't activated and I need the package `nb_conda` to activate it, which I then installed.
Now its possible for me to select and activate `myenv` and to import the aforesaid package. However, if I switch to *any other* environment ("Change kernel"), then the package `astropy` is still loaded, eventhough it is *not* installed.

Now Im thinking that the kernel wasn't switched afterall. But this also cannot be, since it's not possible for `myenv`to load any other package of another environment.

What am I missing?

Cheers

**EDIT 1:** I just noticed: whenever I run the aforesaid package in the base (?) environment `Python3`, then a hidden directory `.astropy` is created in my home path `C:\Users\me\`. In this hidden directory I can see two `.cfg`-files. Maybe this all has something to do with my question?

Why at all is this hidden directory created? Does every python package create such a hidden folder?

Comment: You seem to have assimilated some misinformation about how to use Jupyter with Conda. Please read the information in [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/570918). You should not be activating the kernel environment. Instead, keep a dedicated Jupyter environment with `nb_conda_kernels` installed and always launch from there. `nb_conda` is irrelevant to your problem and is not required.

Comment: Thank you @merv for hinting that! It sure works now with `nb_conda_kernels` installed. The only thing that still confuses me is why other kernels, that are switched to in jupyter notebook, can import a package that the don't have?

Comment: Packages from other identically versioned Python installations (other envs, system- or user-level Python) can leak into a current env through environment variables like `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`. I would check things like `import sys; print(sys.path)` or, in the case of a particular package, `import astropy; print(astropy.__spec__)`, to track down exactly where Python is loading things from. Considering adding that info to your question.