# Cannot select Jupyter Python Kernel in notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I am using Visual Studio Code, Jupyter and Anaconda 3.8.5. I have a notebook, in that notebook I cannot select the kernel I want. The kernel is visible, I can click on it, a pop-up below appears stating kernel is switching, but it is not selected.

What I have tried:

- Check ipykernel is installed.
- Reinstalled Jupyter in that environment.
- Tried restarting Visual Studio Code.
- Restarted machine.
- Tried to see if I could set the kernel using a Visual Studio Code workspace setting (nope).

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: Might be related to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379391/10039621

Comment: I got it working by deleting my venv and recreating but this time installing ipykernel through the visual studio code gui. I opened the notebook and the pop-up for installing ipykernel appeared I selected yes and it now works. Seems like a visual studio code environment problem.