# conda R env not showing up in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter, conda

I am able to add a new conda python env in jupyter notebook using the suggestions in this link.

[Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name test_env --display-name "Python (test_env)"
```

I have conda R environment (r_env) and tried to do following:-

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name r_env --display-name "r_env"`.

However as expected this creates a python kernel and not R in jupyter.

What is the correct way of doing so for conda r envirnoment?

Answer (score 2):

this link below solved my problem.
https://izoda.github.io/site/anaconda/r-jupyter-notebook/