# An error occurred while importing the library dlib

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Here I installed the library as follows dlib(Jupyter Anaconda 3):

```bash
conda create -n envname 

conda activate envname

conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

But there is an error in the ..ipynb file when importing the library.

[image: error]

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and you could install module for one Python but you run code with other Python. If you run script with `python script.py` then you could use `python -m pip install dlib` to install module in correct Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d25f48e861da> in <module>
----> 1 import dlib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'