# New conda environments no longer being recognised in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Whenever I have previously run Jupyter notebooks from within an activated conda environment, the environment is available within Jupyter. However, now when I do this with any newly created environment this doesn't work anymore. If I use a previously created environment I can access the environment through Jupyter, it is only newly created environments which don't work!

I have tried installing nb_conda_kernels ipykernel and ipywidgets as described in another stack overflow question but this also doesn't solve the issue.

Any ideas how I can get this working again and which packages might not be installed for this to work?

Edit: If I follow the top answer on this post [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook) then the environment becomes available. However I would need to run this for every new environment! Any reason this behavior could have changed?

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
conda create --name firstEnv
conda activate firstEnv
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=firstEnv
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it was problem with the Jupyter and Ipykernel packages in the base Conda environment which I should have thought of checking before posting!

Comment: Despite reinstalling jupyter and ipykernel packages in the base environment, this still didn't work for me until I included this line in the new env:  python -m ipykernel install --user --name=firstEnv.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem I solved this by reinstalling the Jupyter and Ipykernel packages in the base conda environment.