# Conda environment.yml - automatically add environment and extensions to Jupyter

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

Whenever I install a sample `environment.yml`, say:

```yaml
name: my_env
dependencies:
  - python
  - numpy
  - pip:
    - scipy
    - ipykernel
    - ipywidgets
```

that I install by `conda env create -f environment.yml` I then always have to add it to the Jupyter "kernelspec":

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env --display-name "my_env"
```

and enable extensions:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

It would be simpler to have these two steps part of the `environment.yml` to start off with. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you aware of `nb_conda_kernels`? e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409235/570918). That is the solution for auto-registration. Not sure about the widgets - do they need to be installed in the kernel or is it sufficient to install it in the environment with just Jupyter/Jupyterlab?