# How to upgrade the version of python for jupyter lab?

Tags: python, conda, jupyter-lab

I used to anaconda to upgrade the python version from 3.9 to 3.11 in command, however jupyter lab still use 3.9 version. how do I use 3.11 version in jupyter lab?

```
% conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/zeni/opt/anaconda3
py311                    /Users/zeni/opt/anaconda3/envs/py311
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/570918. The idiomatic thing to do is add the `py311` environment as a "*kernel*", rather than change anything about the environment with Jupyter. That is, run `conda install -n py311 ipykernel` and when you run Jupyter you should see an option to use that.

Answer (score 1):

`conda update` won't update python version and you have to create a new environment with the python version you want and of course the other modules that you need, including jupyterlab

```bash
conda create -n py311 python=3.11 # create an env with right python version
conda activate py311 # switch to your newly created env
conda install jupyterlab # install jupyterlab module in this env
```

in your case, you are still using `base` env, switch to your `py311` env and install jupyterlab as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activate the "py311" environment: In your terminal, run the following command to activate the "py311" environment:
```

conda activate py311

```
Install Jupyter Lab in the "py311" environment: While the "py311" environment is active, run the following command to install Jupyter Lab:
```

conda install jupyterlab

```
Register the "py311" environment as a Jupyter kernel: To make Jupyter Lab recognize the "py311" environment, you need to register it as a kernel. Run the following command:
```

python -m ipykernel install --user --name=py311 --display-name="Python 3.11"

```
Launch Jupyter Lab: Start Jupyter Lab by running the following command:
```

jupyter lab

```
Select the "Python 3.11" kernel: In the Jupyter Lab interface, when creating a new notebook or changing the kernel of an existing notebook, you can select the "Python 3.11" kernel from the kernel dropdown menu.
```