# anaconda install pymc3 & tensorflow failed

Tags: python, anaconda, pymc3

I'm setting up Python environment for my new computer, when I try to use `conda install pymc3` (or tensorflow), there always have a problem when solving the environment.

```
(base) PS C: Users lzzhu>pymc3condainstall
Channels:
- defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: warning libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
```

My computer is Windows 11 x64, Python 3.11.5, conda version : 23.10.0, Anaconda 2023.09

There is a similar problem in stackoverflow but also not be solved. [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268673/cannot-install-matplotlib-in-python-3-12)

Comment: Where is the error message? Only see a warning. Have you tried creating a new environment - generally installing in **base** is a recipe for problems (despite Anaconda's blue-sky documentation).