# Install R in Jupyter Notebok on mac

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Hi stackoverflow community,

I am trying to download R to appear in my Jupyter notebook. Currently i only have Python.

Thanks.

I have tried to follow this guide https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/verify-install/
but the R option is greyed out and i am unable to choose.

[see here for what i see on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMHFz.png)

I also tried to download r-irkernel from Anaconda navigator but it also not working.

Is there any other method i can get R dropdown in my Jupyter notebook? I do have R installed on my mac? Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why you refer to a that guide that has nothing to do with adding the R kernel to your Anaconda install. It reflects a lack of research, which is emphasized as the second subsection in the guide [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's numerous guides out there to do what you are attempting. Examples: [here](https://izoda.github.io/site/anaconda/r-jupyter-notebook/), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydScgWT6yOU), [here](https://datatofish.com/r-jupyter-notebook/), etc.. You mention the 'r-irkernel' as an aside in your post when ...

Comment: <continued> this is the main thrust of what you should be trying to do. Also, you probably want to install 'nb_conda_kernels' and use that to make sure you allow connecting the installed irkernel to Jupyter, see the bottom paragraph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786736/8508004) as how to do that using conda on your command line of your system. Then work through what [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/8508004) says. The first resources I touch on may not reference tnb_conda_kernels but the latter reference is the most thorough option and sets you up for other kernels too.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to download R from here:

https://cran.r-project.org/