# Can't import PyWavelets on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: import, jupyter, pywavelets

I'm trying to use PyWavelets on a Jupyter Notebook. I've used "conda install pywavelets" both in my conda environment and then run a Jupyter Notebook in the same conda environment. However, when I try:

```
import pywavelets
```

or

```
import pywt
```

I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

I've checked with conda list and pywavelets is definitely installed. I tried installing the package in my base environment in case that mattered, and switched my Jupyter Notebook kernel back-and-forth between the base and virtual environments. I also tried a pip install command and it said the package was already installed (as expected).
Some additional info: I'm running Python 3.12.1 on Windows 10, and the verion of pywavelets installed is 1.5.0. I tried running Python in Anaconda Prompt and import pywt works just fine there.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You aren't saying how and where you installed or where you checked `conda list`. Jupyter requires steps to link to the kernel to environment you set up. Did you do that? The easiest way is to use the magic install `%conda install conda-forge::pywavelets` in a notebook where you want to run the import statement. And then restart the kernel. Do `%conda list` in the notebook to check what is in the environment where it is running. (You may want to try that before you try the `%conda install` to see the difference, hopefully.)

Comment: Note you'll want to check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786736/8508004) for what I was saying at the start if you don't want to install again but want to use the environment you already set up. Note one option there is to add `nb_conda_kernels` to make it more convenient to choose the kernels in Jupyter.