# Why two options co-appeared in jupyter notebook's kernels after installing ipykernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I used conda-command as following to create a new environment called `exp1` and installed `ipykernel` in it:

```
conda create -n exp1
conda activate exp1
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name=exp1
jupyter notebook
```

**Inside `file` I tried to use `jupyter notebook` to `new` a project, but I found that there are two kernels called `Python [conda env:exp1]` and `exp1` to be opted in `new`.**

I tried to search this scenario but it seemed that many people do not meet format like `Python [conda env:exp1]` after they installed the `ipykernel`.

Could anyone explain it, please? I would appreciate it for your kindness and patience.

Comment: I suspect you did add two things with the `exp1`in the name and so that us why two are listed. Following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958537/8508004) where you ran `ipython kernel install --user --name=exp1`, that should have been `ipykernel linstall --user --name=exp1`or **even better `python -m ipykernel linstall --user --name=exp1`, based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958537/8508004). You may or may not need nb_conda if everything works without it. You may just want to overlook the extra one you created or look around for how to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for discussing，I tested it last night and found that if only `conda install ipykernel` is executed, jupyter notebook did have the env option `Python [conda env:exp1]`, without `ipython kernel install --user --name=exp1`.

Comment: I found `kernel.json` in my path `D:\anaconda3\envs\exp1\share\jupyter\kernels\python3`, and if `ipython kernel install --user --name=exp1` is executed, a new `kernel.json` appeared in jupyter kernel's path `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels`. Both of them lead to same python. Does it mean jupyter could auto-discover the kernel in conda environment? Thank you.

Comment: Ohh...I just note that I installed nb_conda in jupyter notebook, that's why an extra option `Python [conda env:exp1]`  appeared, now I know... Thank you so much for your help!