# Pyaudio installed with Conda but not found on Import

Tags: python, conda, python-import, pyaudio

I have installed pyaudio with conda, but my jupyter notebook can't find the module pyaudio on import. I have trying uninstalling and reinstalling with no success. Here is a few relevant information:

On my second attempt, I first ran `conda config --add channels conda-forge` and then `conda install pyaudio`. Packages installed this way were:

| Package | Build |
| --- | --- |
| alsa-lib-1.2.11 | hd590300_1 542 KB conda-forge |
| jack-1.9.22 | h7c63dc7_2 453 KB conda-forge |
| libdb-6.2.32 | h9c3ff4c_0 23.3 MB conda-forge |
| libopus-1.3.1 | h7f98852_1 255 KB conda-forge |
| openssl-3.2.1 | hd590300_1 2.7 MB conda-forge |
| portaudio-19.6.0 | h7c63dc7_9 113 KB conda-forge |
| pyaudio-0.2.14 | py311h459d7ec_0 37 KB conda-forge |

This was better than the first time (without conda-forge), where I just got the last two packages.

Other relevant information:

- My version of python is 3.11.8
- `conda list | grep pyaudio` yields
  pyaudio                   0.2.14          py311h459d7ec_0    conda-forge
- Conda and python (3) seems to be in the same path, that is running `which` on them gives:
  `/home/andrea/anaconda3/bin/conda`
  `/home/andrea/anaconda3/bin/python`
  `/home/andrea/anaconda3/bin/python3`
- `pip show pyaudio` gives

```
    Name: PyAudio
    Version: 0.2.14
    Summary: Cross-platform audio I/O with PortAudio
    Home-page: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
    Author: Hubert Pham
    Author-email:
    License: MIT
    Location: /home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages
    Requires:
    Required-by:
```

- Running the code on a script audio-attempt.py instead of jupyter does not change the error
- `echo $PYTHONPATH` yields an empty string. However, I guess there is a default value if the latter is empty, since other modules are normally loaded.

If you need anything else, I will be happy to share. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you installed things via conda and seen them in Jupyter before? You need to connect Jupyter to the environment and from your description, I'm not following if you addressed that. You would have needed to do it with others and so that is why I asked. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/8508004). Optionally, just run `%conda install anaconda::pyaudio` (based on [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyaudio)) in a new cell in the notebook where you want to import.

Comment: Aside, whatever `pip` says will not in generally tell you anything informative at all. You are using Anaconda/conda as you primary package manager by choosing that. You should avoid mixing and matching with `pip` as that is not your primary package manager any longer by choice and using it will lead to unrobust environments that aren't portable. You should only resort to dealing with it when there is no conda recipe.

Comment: I forgot to also include the reference for the magic install commands. In 2019, the modern `%conda install` command was added so that you could run it in a running notebook and be sure that it will install in the environment that the active kernel is running. See more about the added magic install commands for running inside an active Jupyter `.ipynb` file [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Comment: Dear Wayne, thank you very much for your dedication. I have started using conda for a few weeks and I am not sure anymore how I should use it. I thought it was 'just' a dependency-resolver for packages in several languages, so that by running `conda install my_module` it would have taken care of making it work by installing all the necessary stuff. I get it that I shouldn't mix pip and conda because they could possibly manage packages in different ways. 

What still puzzles me are "environments". What are they? [continue]

Comment: [continue] To answer your question, I am trying to connect jupyter and my environment (called base) with the answer you posted in the first comment. I ran `source activate base` (was already active though), `pip install ipykernel`, `python -m ipykernel install --user --name --display-name "Python (base)"`. Then install nb_conda via `conda install nb_conda_kernels`. Should this procedure make packages available on jupyter notebooks (which are, I guess, linked to a specific environment) automatically? Thanks.

Comment: It now works if I launch jupyter notebook from terminal (in the base environment) and then select the file but, mysteriously enough, If i double click on a jupyter notebook directly it can't find pyaudio. I guess it does not open the notebook in the environment. Weird since I don't have other environments... How can I fix this? Side notes: when I try to open a jupyter notebook directly it redirects to google chrome, where *most of the times* a gray screen appears (but sometimes, the content shows up); I have to manually copy the link (with token) from the terminal to Mozilla, where it works.

Comment: For the benefit of other users, in this particular case of pyaudio I also had to run `sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-utils alsa-tools` because some files were missing. Not sure why, conda-forge had not installed all the relevant stuff on its own. Now it works.

Comment: I don't know the recipe it uses. I suspect it is on github. I know it is better than `pip` about handling installing things that hardware needs; however, I'm not sure of the limitations myself. Hopefully your helpful advice will help someone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257254/discussion-between-andrea-marino-and-wayne).