Issue with executing mamba init --all command in Jupyter Notebook
I've encountered an issue when trying to execute the mamba init --all command in Jupyter Notebook. I have installed Mamba and Jupyter Notebook, but despite this, after executing the mamba init --all command in a new notebook and restarting the shell, I still receive the following error:
Run 'mamba init' to be able to run mamba activate/deactivate
and start a new shell session. Or use conda to activate/deactivate.

It's worth noting that mamba activate works in the Bash terminal. Additionally, Jupyter Notebook recognizes Mamba and the installed environments.
I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations on how to solve this issue.
Thank you!

start a new shell?

@marscher Tried doing that, the issue persists

could you please provide more details, you said you invoked the init command inside a jupyter notebook. Did you do that with the builtin "! cmd"? Maybe the mamba command invocation does not invoke a shell, but rather directly invoke the command in question.

@marscher Thank you for your response, I've found a solution.

@marscher I tried "! cmd" and "%%bash", unfortunately it didn't work.

using another environment as kernel inside jupyter (lab) was not the question - anyways.

@marscher You're right, however, I couldn't find another way to solve this problem.

actual question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook/43197286#43197286

As described here, conda stopped automatically setting up environments as Jupyter kernels. You can also find links to the documentation there. In my case, the following worked:
mamba install nb_conda_kernels
pip install ipykernel
mamba activate myenv
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
mamba deactivate

You need to install ipykernel in every environment you want to use in Jupyter Notebook.
I'll be glad if more suitable solutions are suggested.

what is nb_conda_kernels used for, never seen this in this context?

This is my first experience with this extension, as stated in the repository: This extension allows a Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab application within one Conda environment to access kernels for Python, R, and other languages from other environments. When selecting a kernel from an external environment, the kernel's Conda environment is automatically activated before launching the kernel.

The problem is that conda/mamba is not initialized in a user's environment because .bashrc script is not executed by shell in Jupyter on startup.
I have solved this issue on k8s JupyterHub setup by adding this .bash_profile file with the contents below to the user's home directory (in JupyterHub case it is /home/jovyan):
# Get the aliases and functions
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi


After that mamba works properly:
(base) jovyan@jupyter-xxx:~$ mamba env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/conda


