# Extracting columns as vectors from pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatable, pandas-groupby

I created this table using pandas' groupby function and want to extract each column as vector/array 
`df_duration_means = df.groupby('Duration').mean()`

|  | Interest | Loan amount | LTV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Duration |  |  |  |
| 6 | 0.107500 | 274000.000000 | 0.652500 |
| 9 | 0.112500 | 510500.000000 | 0.580000 |
| 12 | 0.105345 | 276632.758621 | 0.595517 |
| 15 | 0.080000 | 81000.000000 | 0.678000 |
| 18 | 0.109167 | 516557.666667 | 0.455867 |
| 24 | 0.101500 | 374500.000000 | 0.554800 |

Now I want to extract a vector for each of the 4 columns (including duration). But I was not able to do it, even checking pandas documentation and all possible similar threads.

```
dur = df_duration_means.index
print(dur)
interest_mx = df_duration_means['Loan amount']
print(interest_mx)
```

So that I can plot each column vector vs the duration vector:

```
fig =  plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.plot(dur,in,color=)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.reset_index()` first, and then use method `.tolist()`. Like this:

```
df_duration_means = df_duration_means.reset_index()
duration = df_duration_means.index.tolist()
interest = df_duration_means['Interest'].tolist()
loan_amount = df_duration_means['Loan amount'].tolist()
ltv = df_duration_means['LTV'].tolist()
```

And then, use `duration`, `interest`, `loan_amount`, and `ltv` as an input into plotly

EDIT: There is simpler solution using plotly.express:

```
import plotly.express as px 
df_duration_means = df_duration_means.reset_index()
fig = px.line(df_duration_means, x=df_duration_means.index, y=['Interest', 'Loan amount', 'LTV'])
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. The first one worked out quite well!

For the second one I had issues with Jupyter recognizing plotly. For anyone having the same issue, here is a corresponding thread (that did not help me :D):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959782/plotly-in-jupyter-issue